# change row colour in a loop based on value

Tags: php

I wish to change tr background colour based on value in a loop so if the value is X for next a few records then colour should be blue, if the value is changed to something else then colour should also be changed to yellow.

My code below is faulty which makes all the rows yellow after painting first one as blue.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  if ($old_value == $value)
  {
    $colour = 'blue';
  }
  else
  {
    $colour = 'yellow';
    $old_value = $value;
  }

}
```

I need output like this:
[image]

Comment: How is that code faulty? What does it do, that it's not supposed to? Or what doesn't it do, that it should?

Comment: how are u changing the color?

Comment: Image added for better explanation.

Comment: @MadMax I changed my answer(I missunderstood the question), have you tried my edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the color according to the last color used, something like

```
$arr = array(1,1,1,4,4,7,3);
$old_value = 0;
$colour = 'blue';
echo '<table>';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if ($old_value == $value)
    {
        //colour stays the same
    }
    else
    {
        if($colour == 'blue')
        {
            $colour = 'yellow';
        }
        else
        {
            $colour = 'blue';
        }
        $old_value = $value;
    }
    echo '<tr style="background-color:' .$colour . '"><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>'; 
}
echo '</table>';
```

Now every group of equal values will have the same colour, and the next group has the other colour.
[image: Looks like this]

Comment: All rows appear as blue now.

Comment: I just completed my example, and it looks like your picture on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using your cycle right:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  if ($old_value == $value)
  {
    $colour = 'blue';
  }
  else
  {
    $colour = 'yellow';
    $old_value = $value;
  }

  //now $color has the desired value
  //so now you should echo your tr

}

//now $color contains just the last row
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = ['something', 'something else', 'another something'];
$old_value = "";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if ($old_value == $value){
        $colour = 'blue';
    }
    else{
    $colour = 'yellow';
    $old_value = $value;
    }
    echo '<tr style="background-color:' .$colour . '"><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>'; 
    }
```

Outputs:

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

you may do like

```
$i=0;
$old_value = "";

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  if ($old_value != $value)
  {
    $old_value = $value;
    $i++;
  }

  if($i % 2 == 1)
  {
    $colour = 'yellow';        
  } else {
    $colour = 'blue';  
  }

}
```

Comment: This make every row different color. If value X comes in next two rows then next two rows should be the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i=0;
 foreach($resultex as $rowex)
      {
 if ($old_value != $rowex)
      {
        $old_value = $rowex;
        $i++;
      }

    if($i%2 == 1)
               {
             <tr  style="background-color:#f3f3f3;color:#000;">
       }
            else 
               {
              <tr  style="background-color:#fff;color:#000;">
       }
     }
```